# Error: Attempt to execute SCRIPT as function

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I'm new to MATLAB and I'm trying to run the exact code given in [Matlab's Help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html): [Color based segmentation using Kmeans](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/color-based-segmentation-using-k-means-clustering.html).

I need to use `Kmeans` for my image but I keep getting this error:

> error: Attempt to execute SCRIPT kmeans as function

The code I tried to run is:

```
[cluster_idx cluster_center] = kmeans(ab,nColors,'distance','sqEuclidean','Replicates',5);'
```

Comment: is it possible you override `kmeans`? try `>> which kmeans` and see if it points to matlab's build-in function. If this is not the case, try `>> clear kmeans` and try again.

Comment: @Shai +1. In fact, @user1974676, you may have saved your script as `kmeans.m`?